# Passing in an entity's property in Entity Framework in LINQ

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, linq-to-sql

I'm not sure if my question makes sense but here we go. I have a very complicated query that gets translated into SQL from EF that relies on runtime variables.

Example: Lets say I have an entity object.

```cs
public class Foobar
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public double AmountOne { get; set; } 
    public double AmountTwo { get; set; } 
}
```

And I want to query one of Foobar's amount fields based on a runtime property. Right now I know there is two ways to do this.

Way #1: In code

```cs
public bool ShouldGetFirstAmount {get; set;}
public double GetFirstAmount()
{
    if (ShouldGetFirstAmount)
    {
        return repository.Foobars.Select(c => c.AmountOne).First();
    } else {
        return repository.Foobars.Select(c => c.AmountTwo).First();
    }
}
```

**Pros**: Smaller sql query, lower overhead
**Cons**: Huge codechunck/ repetitive

Way #2: Straight in the query and EF can transform it.

```cs
public bool ShouldGetFirstAmount {get; set;}
public double GetFirstAmount()
{
        return repository.Foobars.Select(c => ShouldGetFirstAmount ? c.AmountOne : c.AmountTwo).First();
}
```

**Pros**: Smaller code chunck. 
**Cons**: Query performance suffers due to the expression in the actuyal query

So I'm looking for a 3rd way that allows me to get the best of both worlds. I want to be able to pass in the actual object property that should be computed. I'm just not sure how it should be done or if it can even be done.

Something that works kind of like this. I know this code doesn't work but I think you guys get the idea I'm going for.

```cs
public Expression<double> FirstAmountProperty {get; set;}
public double GetFirstAmount()
{
    return repository.Foobars.Select(FirstAmountProperty).First();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're close. If `repository.Foobars` is of type `IQueryable<Foobar>` the expression needs to be of type `Expression<Func<Foobar, double>>`.

However if `repository.Foobars` is of type `IEnumerable<Foobar>`, then it can ALSO be `Func<Foobar, double>` (it call also be `Expression<Func<Foobar, double>>`

Visual studio seems to like this:

```
public Expression<Func<Foobar, double>> FirstAmountExpr
{
    get
    {
        if (ShouldGetFirstAmount)
        {
            return x => x.AmountOne;
        }
        else
        {
            return x => x.AmountTwo;
        }
    }
}

public double GetFirstAmount()
{
    return repository.Foobars.Select(FirstAmountExpr).First();
}
```

Comment: I see. Just read up on expressions and stuff and this all makes a lot more sense now. Thanks.